# npx command to deploy AWS resource is not working and throwing error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-code-deploy, npx

I am trying to run the npx command to deploy the configuration, which throws the below error:

An error occurred when bootstrapping the environment.
{
"message": "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1",
"code": "CredentialsError"
}

However I have set the AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 in the environment variable in the Windows system.
Could anyone let me know am I missing anything else?